# I solve the file owner problem that is pecuilar to linux user.What is the wrong in my dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As mentioned above, I have a file owner problem with Laravel setup.
https://www.fullstaq.com/knowledge-hub/blogs/docker-and-the-host-filesystem-owner-matching-problem
This site has the solution.but the example of dockerfile in this site is for debian.

I want to create apache dockerfile.So Not suitable for what I want to do.

below is my dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

```
# Dockerfile 

FROM php:7.3-apache

COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

COPY --from=composer:2.0 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update  \
    && apt-get -y install \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    vim \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql bcmath mbstring \
    && a2enmod rewrite
    
WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

# I added below the code,but An error occurred with the code. 
ARG uid
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser
```

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src/backend:/var/www/html
      # - /etc/group:/etc/group:ro
      # - /etc/user:/etc/user:ro
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    build:
      context: ./docker/mysql
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

What is the wrong in my dockerfile?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting here is

```
useradd: invalid user ID '-d'
```

This is because with

```
ARG uid
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/devuser devuser
```

you specified a [build `ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) which is used in the following `RUN` directive. But when building the image with `docker-compose` there is no actual value specified for that `ARG`.

So when building it is substituted with an empty string and the executed command becomes

```bash
useradd -G www-data,root -u -d /home/devuser devuser
```

You need to specify a value for `uid` (i.e. the uid of your user on the host system) with the [`args` attribute in the `docker-compose.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#args):

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        uid: 1000
        # or using env variables:
        # uid: $HOST_UID
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
docker-compose up works well, but file owner problem remains unfixed.